# Local thread variable or new thread - Java

Tags: java

I have a class that implements Runnable.  For logging reasons I want to know the Thread that has been used to run the class.  In that case would it be best to do

```
public class WebSocketHandle implements Runnable {
   private Thread myThread; // access to thread for logging

   public void start() {
      myThread = new Thread(this);
      myThread.start();
   }
}
```

Then in the method that creates these I do something like:

```
    public void newSocket(Socket socket)
{
    WebSocketHandle handle = new WebSocketHandle(this, socket,_identity);
    _sockets.add(handle);

    EventLog.write("Socket assigned for new connection (" + _sockets.size() + ") "  + handle.toString() +  ". No value received yet yet...", getClass().getName(), "register");

    // Start thread listening for data
    new Thread(handle).start();
}
```

Or is it best to have something like:

```
public class WebSocketHandle implements Runnable {
   private String myThread;

   public void setThreadOwner(string threadId) {
      myThread = threadId;
   }
}
```

Then it would be used as such:

```
WebSocketHandle handle = new WebSocketHandle();
Thread newThread = new Thread(handle);

newThread.start();

handle.setThreadOwner(handle.toString());
```

I can't help but feel the second option is better practice but the code to write seems clumsier??

EDIT:  In response to Aaron's comments:

1. This is for a Web server socket handling code so the Thread will be running indefinetly.  I had not considered using ThreadPools so maybe that is something I need to consider
2. I log various activities (i.e. data received and sent) in the the WebSocketHandle class so I wanted to tie the logging events to the Thread instance that it is running on.  To do that I found the easiest way was to log the thread.toString() as part of the log output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply call `Thread.currentThread()` to get the thread which is executing the code right now.

To help identifying a thread, use `new Thread("some useful name");`

**[EDIT]** Both of your approaches have some drawbacks. The first approach always creates a thread, so you can't execute the runnable in, say, a thread pool. And eventually, you will want to do that. Unfortunately, when you find out that you do, your application will have become very complex and it will be hard to change.

Also the "thread" doesn't help you much; it's usually irrelevant which thread started something. When looking for bugs, you want to know which piece of code executed a method. So it would make more sense to pass a `Logger` into `start()`.

That said, what do you mean by "access to thread for logging"? What information does the anonymous thread created in `start()` contain which might be useful for logging? Since it has a generated name and you still don't know who called `start()`, the first approach looks completely useless to me.

The second approach allows you to give the `Runnable` a name but a) it doesn't compile and b) doesn't make any sense either (not mentioning the fact that the variable names are confusing).

To get the class of something, you can call `getClass().getName()`; there is no point in setting the class name of the instance using a setter. So the second approach is dangerously confusing and it violates the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Also, it doesn't give you much useful information for logging: It doesn't tell you who created the instance of `MyClass` and if you wanted a logger for `MyClass`, you can simply use this line:

```
private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

There is no need for the setter.

So my conclusion is that both approaches should be avoided.

Comment: Cheers Aaron.  Is there a particular reason why the second approach would be better?

Comment: Cheers Aaron.  Makes more sense now.  I hadn't considered using ThreadPools so maybe that's something I need to look into